# List of prime numbers as a string in Java in a given Range

Tags: java

The question is:
Write a java program to print all prime numbers in the interval [a,b] (a and b, both inclusive).

Conditions are:

- Input 1 should be lesser than Input 2. Both the inputs should be positive.
- Range must always be greater than zero.
- If any of the condition mentioned above fails, then display "Provide valid input"
- Use a minimum of one for loop and one while loop.

I came up with a code like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PrimeNumbers{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        if((a > b) || a <= 0 || b <= 0){
            System.out.println("Provide valid input");
        }
        else{
            int i = 0, num = 0;
            String prime = "";

            for(i = a;i <= b;i++){
                int counter = 0;
                num = i;
                while(num >= 1){
                    if(i % num == 0)
                        counter++;
                    num--;
                }
                if(counter == 2)
                    prime = prime + i + " ";
            }

            System.out.println(prime);
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it against test cases. One of the hidden test case just gave a hint "Check for equal range"
I am not sure what that means. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what if both your `a` and your `b` variable are 7 ?

Comment: try adding '|| a = b' in your if statement that checks for valid input

Comment: @AdilOoze this is not a comparaison. This is an assignment. I think you are looking for `|| a == b`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it was a typo :)

Comment: I guess the only thing I can see is that `b-a >= 1` must hold. BTW, you can use `sc.nextInt()` so there is no need to parse.

Comment: "Check for equal range" at a guess, I think this is referring to the "Input 1 should be lesser than Input 2" requirement. You're not correctly checking that.

Comment: `if ((a > b...` should be `if ((a >= b...`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
package monu;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int c = b - a;
        if(a > b || c < 0 || a < 0|| b <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Provide valid input");
        }
        else{
            int i = 0, num = 0;
            String prime = "";

            for(i = a; i <= b; i++){
                int counter = 0;
                num = i;
                while (num >= 1) {
                    if (i % num == 0)
                        counter++;
                    num--;
                }
                if (counter == 2)
                    prime = prime + i + " ";
            }

            System.out.println(prime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to show with this code? Please explain, rather than just dumping code. (But I can't see what relevance checking `b-a < a` has with respect to the requirements).

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake I want to write c<0 